# How can I pass and get reducer function through Link in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a reducer function inside a link like this:

```
 <Link 
       to={{
       pathname: '/location',
         state:{
            listinput: addList
         }
       }}>
```

But when I try to access the parameter like that:

```
props.inputList
```

I get error :"react_devtools_backend.js:3973 Warning: Invalid values for props `listinputs` on  tag"
I would be happy for help on how to pass the function correctly

Comment: You shouldn't need to and it's not good practice, what if they refresh the page? Instead have an ID on your url like `location/:id` and using this ID select the relevant list/item

Comment: I would suggest to bind the function in the component using mapDispatchToProps instead of passing it in the Link, the prop will be empty if you refresh the page.